# swift : Failed to communicate with Interface Builder

Tags: ios, swift

I've just opened existing project in xcode 6 beta. But it's crash with following error message.

```
dyld: problem loading iOS simulator dyld
2014-06-05 11:15:06.604 ibtoold[952:507] Init failed: Error Domain=IBMessageChannelErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to communicate with Interface Builder" UserInfo=0x7fd09861dbf0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to communicate with Interface Builder, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool crashed: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP), IBCrashLog=

Dyld Error Message:
  problem loading iOS simulator dyld
}
2014-06-05 11:15:06.605 ibtoold[952:507] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-6154.17/InterfaceBuilderKit/Utilities/IBAbstractMessageChannelInterfaceBuilderToolManager.m:76
Details:  Failed to attach to Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool with error: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool." UserInfo=0x7fd09b3a1360 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd09861d710 "Failed to communicate with Interface Builder", NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (962) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 5.



Dyld Error Message:
  problem loading iOS simulator dyld
}
Object:   <IBCocoaTouchToolManager: 0x7fd09b478a40>
Method:   -attachToToolForTargetRuntime:scaleFactor:assertOnFailureToAttach:assertOnPostLaunchRequestFailures:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fd098614780>{name = (null), num = 1}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2014-06-05 11:15:06.914 ibtoold[952:507] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-6153.11/InterfaceBuilder/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:45
Details:  Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool." UserInfo=0x7fd09b3a1360 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd09861d710 "Failed to communicate with Interface Builder", NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (962) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 5.
```

Is any workaround for xib to run on xcode beta?

Comment: happened same Quit and restart ,

Comment: Did you mean xcode or mac? I already restart my xcode. but didn't work.

Comment: Try restarting your Mac.

Comment: FYI people get reamed for talking about pre-release / beta software on SOF and I'm surprised you didn't. +1 as this helped solve my issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This fixes the Interface Builder issue.

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app
cd Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform  
cd Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib  
sudo mv dyld_sim dyld_sim.orig
```

Comment: Happy to be of service :)

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Rebooting my Mac did.  Anyone know why this happens?  Why the above 'mv' is proposed as a fix?

Answer (score 7):

According to @ThePaddedCell, I did the following steps, it's finally worked for me

1) `Move` xcode6-beta into application folder

2) `Restart` mac and open xcode6-beta from application folder.

but I don't know why.. If anyone know this reason, welcome to update my answer.

Comment: I didn't have to restart the Mac. Copying to /Applications fixed this problem for me.

Comment: This did solve the problem of Xcode beta even with `Version 8.0 beta (8S128d)`  Error was  - `Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (1122) failed to launch and exited with status 11`

Answer (score 0):

Move your Xcode to Application then Check it if still problem is not solved then restart your Mac and open the xcode from the application.