# Xcode 9.3 suddenly not parsing storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

suddenly Xcode 9.3 storyboard give me an error " An internal error occurred. Editing function may be limited"

I try to:

- clean project
- remove DerivedData
- disable csrutil
- update Mac to latest, even to beta
- update to xcode 9.4 beta
- I moved the xcode to application path
- Reinstall the CommandLineTools

What else could occur this problem?

below is the error logs:

```
Version = 9.3 (9E145)
Plugin Version = 14109
Beta Version = 0
OS Version = 10.13.5 (17F35e)



=================================
    ERROR:
=================================

Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. (Failure reason: Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (-1) failed to launch): Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool via CoreSimulator spawn (Failure reason: Failed to spawn Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool on IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (F29EB89D-17EA-477A-8140-6F7896E208EB, iOS 11.3, Booted)): The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory (Failure reason: No such file or directory)

Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (-1) failed to launch, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9eba1dddf0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to spawn Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool on IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (F29EB89D-17EA-477A-8140-6F7896E208EB, iOS 11.3, Booted), NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool via CoreSimulator spawn, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9eba2cc080 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}}, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool.}



=================================
    TOOL DESCRIPTION:
=================================

<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7f9eb8dddd40> {
| targetRuntime.identifier: IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater
| _roleString: System content
| deviceTypeDescription: <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7f9eba14a320> scaleFactor=2x
}



=================================
    LAUNCH CONTEXT:
=================================

<IBCocoaTouchToolLaunchContext: 0x7f9eb88dc220> {
| toolDescription.ib_verboseDescription: <IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x7f9eb8dddd40> {
| | targetRuntime.identifier: IBCocoaTouchFramework-ElevenAndLater
| | _roleString: System content
| | deviceTypeDescription: <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x7f9eba14a320> scaleFactor=2x
| }
| launchPath: /Volumes/Data/Download/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool
| frameworkSearchPaths: (
    "/Volumes/Data/Download/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks"
)
| toolName: Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool
| platformName: iphonesimulator
| applicationTool: 0
| processIdentifier: -1
| exitStatus: (null)
| signalStatus: (null)
}



=================================
    EXECUTION CONTEXT:
=================================

<IBSimulatorToolCoreSimulatorBootedCLIExecutionContext: 0x7f9eb84aade0> {
| device: IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (F29EB89D-17EA-477A-8140-6F7896E208EB, iOS 11.3, Booted)
}



=================================
    DEVICE:
=================================

IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (F29EB89D-17EA-477A-8140-6F7896E208EB, iOS 11.3, Booted)



=================================
    TOOL MANAGER:
=================================

<IBCocoaTouchToolManager: 0x7f9eb7fc9920>



=================================
    REASON FOR REQUESTING TOOL:
=================================

Preflighting tools for opening document <IBStoryboardDocument: 0x7f9eb2b91a00>: <IBCocoaTouchTargetRuntime: 0x7f9eb7fd0f70>



=================================
    XCODE BACKTRACE:
=================================

  0   +[IBPlatformToolFailureHandler failureHandlerWithContext:failure:diagnosticsHandlerBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  1   +[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager _THREADSAFE_injectDiagnosticsHandlerWithFailureContext:intoError:forLaunchingToolWithError:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  2   +[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager _THREADSAFE_launchNewToolWithLaunchContext:executionContext:toolProxyClass:failureContext:requestingMethod:error:forReason:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  3   __117-[IBAbstractInterfaceBuilderPlatformToolManager asyncLaunchNewToolWithDescription:queue:completionHandler:forReason:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  5   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   _dispatch_queue_serial_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8   _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9   _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 11   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)




=================================
    SDKS:
=================================

iOS 11.3 (iphoneos11.3):
version = 11.3
platform = com.apple.platform.iphoneos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "C689C3CA-2814-11E8-B440-EB6E943B87E0";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15E217;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "iPhone OS";
    ProductVersion = "11.3";
}

iOS 11.3 (iphoneos11.3):
version = 11.3
platform = com.apple.platform.iphoneos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "C689C3CA-2814-11E8-B440-EB6E943B87E0";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15E217;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "iPhone OS";
    ProductVersion = "11.3";
}

Simulator - watchOS 4.3 (watchsimulator4.3):
version = 4.3
platform = com.apple.platform.watchsimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "4AF39DC2-2782-11E8-A671-639E35235AA8";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15T212;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Watch OS";
    ProductVersion = "4.3";
}

watchOS 4.3 (watchos4.3):
version = 4.3
platform = com.apple.platform.watchos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "4AF39DC2-2782-11E8-A671-639E35235AA8";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15T212;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Watch OS";
    ProductVersion = "4.3";
}

macOS 10.13 (macosx10.13):
version = 10.13
platform = com.apple.platform.macosx
versionInfo = {
    ProductBuildVersion = 17E189;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Mac OS X";
    ProductUserVisibleVersion = "10.13.4";
    ProductVersion = "10.13.4";
}

watchOS 4.3 (watchos4.3):
version = 4.3
platform = com.apple.platform.watchos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "4AF39DC2-2782-11E8-A671-639E35235AA8";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15T212;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Watch OS";
    ProductVersion = "4.3";
}

Simulator - iOS 11.3 (iphonesimulator11.3):
version = 11.3
platform = com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "C689C3CA-2814-11E8-B440-EB6E943B87E0";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15E217;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "iPhone OS";
    ProductVersion = "11.3";
}

tvOS 11.3 (appletvos11.3):
version = 11.3
platform = com.apple.platform.appletvos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "0618144A-275E-11E8-A65D-05CCCC2CB129";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15L211;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
    ProductVersion = "11.3";
}

macOS 10.13 (macosx10.13):
version = 10.13
platform = com.apple.platform.macosx
versionInfo = {
    ProductBuildVersion = 17E189;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Mac OS X";
    ProductUserVisibleVersion = "10.13.4";
    ProductVersion = "10.13.4";
}

Simulator - watchOS 4.3 (watchsimulator4.3):
version = 4.3
platform = com.apple.platform.watchsimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "4AF39DC2-2782-11E8-A671-639E35235AA8";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15T212;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Watch OS";
    ProductVersion = "4.3";
}

Simulator - tvOS 11.3 (appletvsimulator11.3):
version = 11.3
platform = com.apple.platform.appletvsimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "0618144A-275E-11E8-A65D-05CCCC2CB129";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15L211;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
    ProductVersion = "11.3";
}

Simulator - tvOS 11.3 (appletvsimulator11.3):
version = 11.3
platform = com.apple.platform.appletvsimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "0618144A-275E-11E8-A65D-05CCCC2CB129";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15L211;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
    ProductVersion = "11.3";
}

Simulator - iOS 11.3 (iphonesimulator11.3):
version = 11.3
platform = com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "C689C3CA-2814-11E8-B440-EB6E943B87E0";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15E217;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "iPhone OS";
    ProductVersion = "11.3";
}

tvOS 11.3 (appletvos11.3):
version = 11.3
platform = com.apple.platform.appletvos
versionInfo = {
    BuildID = "0618144A-275E-11E8-A65D-05CCCC2CB129";
    ProductBuildVersion = 15L211;
    ProductCopyright = "1983-2018 Apple Inc.";
    ProductName = "Apple TVOS";
    ProductVersion = "11.3";
}
```

Comment: One thing you didn't do is trying to restart your Mac...

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052545/swift-failed-to-communicate-with-interface-builder

Comment: @l'L'l I did more than 10 times, I saw all stack-overflow questions as well as apple support

Comment: Side note: this is a perfect example of why even for solo projects, everyone should use a version control system such as Git.  This way you could add your changes to a new branch, then roll back to your previous successfully built commit, and then verify if it still builds or not.  If it no longer builds, something's wrong with your Xcode or system.  If it does build, there's something wrong with the commit on your branch.

Comment: @Smartcat but this is not depends on the code, it's xcode problem. I had it before in xcode 9.2 then when I fix it by update the mac, my code work like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trying, I just formatted my Mac and the xcode works fine.

I don't know why, even the bug I reported to apple, not resolved!